# pyramid_mailer `Message` and `Content-Transfer-Encoding`

Tags: python, email, smtp, pylons

I'm sending emails with `pyramid_mailer` and found this weird issue that when I use Office365 as my SMTP server it adds random `=` characters into my message. I don't get that issue with any other mail server (I tested this with gmail and also with my own postfix server)

I send emails like below:

```
from pyramid_mailer.mailer import Mailer

from pyramid_mailer.message import Attachment, Message

mailer = Mailer()
mailer.smtp_mailer.hostname = "test.mail.at.office365"
mailer.smtp_mailer.username = "my_user"
mailer.smtp_mailer.password = "secret"
mailer.smtp_mailer.port = 587
mailer.smtp_mailer.tls = True

message = Message(
    subject="Test",
    sender="my_user@my_domain.com",
    recipients="test_user@test_domain.com",
    body="very long text, at least 75 characters long so Office 365 will break it and insert annoying '=' into message",
    html="very long text, at least 75 characters long so Office 365 will break it and insert annoying '=' into message",
)

mailer.send_immediately(message)
```

I searched on google and found this has something to do with line breaks and `Transfer-Content-Encoding`. And indeed, if I add `\r\n` every ~50 characters I won't see `=` added. But the problem is that I might want to send a hyperlink that will be longer than that...

Pyramid documentation (https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_mailer/en/latest/) says I can use `Attachment` rather than plain string. And indeed as soon as I do that I can set this `Transfer-Content-Encoding` to something like `base64` (as suggested here: https://jeremytunnell.com/2009/01/04/really-hairy-problem-with-seemingly-random-crlf-and-spaces-inserted-in-emails/) but my message then shows as attachment, not as regular message...

There seems to be no way to add this `Transfer-Content-Encoding` to `Message` object... I tried to use `Message.extra_headers = {'Transfer-Content-Encoding': 'base64'}` but this did not help.

I'm totally out of ideas, would appreciate any help...

---

-- Edit --

Thanks to answer below from @Mess:

```
from pyramid_mailer.message import Attachment
my_message = "very long text, at least 75 characters long so Office 365 will break it and insert annoying '=' into message"
body_html = Attachment(data=my_message, transfer_encoding="base64", disposition='inline')
body_text = Attachment(data=my_message, transfer_encoding="base64", disposition='inline')
```

Then pass `body_html` and `body_text` to `Message` constructor.

Comment: This sounds like you are examining the raw message, and getting upset that the server does exactly the right thing. If it adds `Content-transfer-encoding: quoted-printable` to the MIME headers then the recipient's email client will take care of unwrapping these lines completely transparently.

Comment: Thanks @tripleee - for some reason gmail clients was not unwrapping my messages when sent through office365...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is "Content-Disposition" header you need to set to control how the content is available to the recipient.

Set it to "attachment" to let download the file, use "inline" to be able to include the content, for example a logo, directly to your email, etc:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition

I hope it will point you to the right direction.

**EDIT:**

Using `pyramid_mailer` package it would be something like:

```py
from pyramid_mailer.message import Attachment
attachment = Attachment(data=some_data, transfer_encoding="base64", disposition='inline')
```